# Integrity Error on object creation in Odoo

Tags: odoo

I am developing a new model called implementation.project; it inherits from project.project. This is the class declaration:

```
class implementation_project(osv.Model):
    _name = 'implementation.project'
    _inherit = 'project.project'
```

Some fields (columns) are added to this class (model or whatever). Original model (project.project) has a *one2many* field called `tasks`. When I try to create new `implementation.project` record, the enigmatic Odoo raises this error:

```
IntegrityError: insert or update on table "project_task_type_rel" violates foreign key constraint "project_task_type_rel_project_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (project_id)=(6) is not present in table "project_project".
```

Obviously!!!! It has to exist `project.project` record to create anything that inherits from him!!! I guess Odoo (according to some, a good platform to develop) has the ability to know how to proceed in this case... or not?

So, how to create new record from `implementation.project`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you defining the form for your `implementation.project`? Also, please show your full class

Answer (score 0):

In Your currenct example, field `tasks` is *one2many* to `project.task` model by field `project_id`:

`'tasks': fields.one2many('project.task', 'project_id', "Task Activities"),`

, which means that Odoo expects `project.task` model to have *many2one* field `project_id` that references `implementation.project` model, but `project.task` model still have field `project_id` as foreign key to `project.project` model:

```
'project_id': fields.many2one('project.project', 'Project', ...)
```

, but Your `implementation.project` is completely new model (and database table).

May be [inheritance by delegation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model._inherits) will better suit for Your needs?

Also look in [inheritance doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html#inheritance)

In this case, your `implementation.project` model will look like:

```
class implementation_project(osv.Model):
    _name = 'implementation.project'
    _inherits = {'project.project': 'project_id'}

    _columns = {
        'project_id': fields.many2one('project.project', 'Project'),
    }
```

This will allow to use all fields of `project.project` model on Your own model, with out no changes.

For examples You may look at `product.template` and `product.product` models code